# $\mathbb{N} \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My professor proved this:
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: n \not\in n$

I proved that: $ n \bigcup \{n\} \not\subset n$

pf.

$Suppose,  n \bigcup \{n\} \subset n$

$\implies  (n \bigcup \{n\})\setminus n  \subset n\setminus n$

$\implies  n\setminus n \bigcup \{n\}\setminus n  \subset n\setminus n$

$\implies \emptyset \bigcup \{n\}\setminus n  \subset \emptyset$

$\implies\{n\}\setminus n  \subset \emptyset$

$Suppose, \{n\}\setminus n = \emptyset$

$\implies n \in n$

$ Since, n \in \mathbb{N}, n \not\in n$

By contradiction $\{n\}\setminus n \not= \emptyset$

Therefore, $\{n\}\setminus n = \{n\} \implies\{n\}  \subset \emptyset$

$\implies n \in\emptyset \implies false$

By contradiction $ n \bigcup \{n\} \not\subset n$∎

But, is there any set $X: X\in X$ is true. In particular are the natural numbers in the natural numbers given that they're infinite.

Comment: $X\in X$ is prohibited in axiom of regularity.

Comment: Cool thanks! @KemonoChen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, is there any set $X:X\in X$ is true.

No (at least not in normal set theories, others exist). This is important, and essentially the reason why axiomatic set theory exists: allowing things like this makes incredibly weird things happen. This is called *well-foundedness* (and it's a direct consequence of the Axiom of Regularity in ZF, the most common set theory).

> In particular are the natural numbers in the natural numbers given that they're infinite.

No. If you want to define natural numbers as sets, the usual definition is that $0 = \emptyset$, and $n = \{n - 1\} \cup (n - 1)$. In particular, all such sets are finite, so $\mathbb{N}\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: My professor defines $0=\emptyset$, but I get it. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I'll edit it to match your version.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently wrong with sets $X$ satisfying $X\in X$. They can be reasoned about just like any other set (which is all we can ask for, I guess).

However, one of the axioms in ZF set theory (which is the most commonly used theory, especially if you count it together with ZFC) is called the *axiom of regularity*. It implies that there are no such sets.

So there is nothing a priori problematic with such sets. They just never occur in the standard theory.

Comment: Good to know, I mean such a set would be really weird, but ok!